# How does one show that a function is continuous over some interval?

Tags: calculus, functions

As title says, how does one show that a function is continuous over some interval (let us say over some interval of real numbers?)

Would(Can) this involve derivative?

Comment: Is there any certain function in the mind?

Comment: No, any general real function.

Answer (score 7):

If you know that a given function $f$ is *differentiable* on some interval $(a, b) \subseteq \mathbb R$, then it certainly follows that $f$ is continuous on that interval (since differentiability requires continuity and more).

But a function $f$ *can be* continuous on an interval, even though it may *not be* differentiable on the entire interval. In such cases, and in general, we have that:

- $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ if and only if the following holds:

  - $\forall x_0 \in (a,b) \subseteq \mathbb R,\;\; \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0);$
  - $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=f(a)\;\;\text{and}\;\;\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = f(b).$

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the support ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to show that:

- $f(x)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, i.e; $\forall x_0\in(a,b), \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$
- $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=f(a),~~\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=f(b)$

I assume you aregoing to show that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity has various equivalent definitions.  The existence of a derivative is a stronger property than continuity, so if you already know the function is differentiable on an interval, then it is certainly continuous, but the [converse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) does not hold.